# Net::SSH::Perl hands without output

Tags: perl, ssh

Hi I am trying to get a connection from windows a unix box and just pass an ls command. The execution just hangs without any output. What might be wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use Net::SSH::Perl;

my $hostname = "unixhost";
my $username = "####";
my $password = "######";

my $cmd = shift;


my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("$hostname", debug=>1,  identity_files => []);
$ssh->login("$username","$password");
my ($stdout,$stderr,$exit) = $ssh->cmd("$cmd");
print $stdout;
exit;
```

*> C:>perl ssh.pl "ls -ltr"
 WXVM0026: Reading configuration data

> c:/.ssh/config WXVM0026: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
>   WXVM0026: Connecting to themse, port 22. WXVM0026: Remote protocol
>   version 1.99, remote software version
>   OpenSSH_4.5p1+sftpfilecontrol-v1.1-hpn12v14 WXVM0026: Net::SSH::Perl
>   Version 1.34, protocol version 1.5. WXVM0026: No compat match:
>   OpenSSH_4.5p1+sftpfilecontrol-v1.1-hpn12v14. WXVM0026: Connection
>   established. WXVM0026: Waiting for server public key. WXVM0026:
>   Received server public key (768 bits) and host key (1024 bits).
>   WXVM0026: Host 'themse' is known and matches the host key. WXVM0026:
>   Encryption type: DES3 WXVM0026: Sent encrypted session key. WXVM0026:
>   Received encryption confirmation. WXVM0026: Doing challenge response
>   authentication. Password: Password: WXVM0026: Sending command: ls -ltr
>   WXVM0026: Entering interactive session.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the remote command does not close its input/output/stederr the SSH session waits for its input forever (at least until its timeoouts).

```
 my $cmd = "ls / 0<&- 1>&- 2>&-";
```

Regards,

Comment: I tried the above, why is it still stuck? :  WXVM0026: Sending command: ls / 0<&- 1>&- 2>&-
WXVM0026: Sending command: ls / 0<&- 1>&- 2>&-
WXVM0026: Requesting service exec on channel 1.
WXVM0026: channel 1: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768