# Net::SSH:Perl can't login SSH1

Tags: perl, ssh, module

I'm trying to connect me to a switch using SSH1 (the switch is old and does not support ssh2) and after the firsts steps, my program dosen't do nothing and i have to Ctrl+C to stop it

```
# Perl v5.8.8 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSH::Perl;

my $host = "10.*.*.*";
my $username = "***";
my $password = "***";


my $cmd = 'show version';
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host, debug => 1);
$ssh->login($username, $password);
my($stdout, $stderr, $exit) = $ssh->cmd($cmd); #the script stops here
print $stdout;
```

logs :

```
 Connecting to 10.*.*.*, port 22.
 Remote version string: SSH-1.5-OpenSSH_2.9p1
 Remote protocol version 1.5, remote software version OpenSSH_2.9p1
 Net::SSH::Perl Version 1.42, protocol version 1.5.
 No compat match: OpenSSH_2.9p1.
 Connection established.
 Waiting for server public key.
 Received server public key (512 bits) and host key (896 bits).
 Host '10.*.*.*' is known and matches the host key.
 Encryption type: DES3
 Sent encrypted session key.
 Received encryption confirmation.
 Trying password authentication.
 Sending command: show version
 Entering interactive session.
 Terminating on signal SIGINT(2) #Ctrl-C
```

i can log me in with putty and it works.

I used wiresharck and we can see that the password and maybe the login are not used counter to putty http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/31/1470038197-troubleshooting2-ssh1.png, packets are too lights. 
I don't understand what's going wrong, why the connection failed and logs say nothing about it.

Comment: Try another command to see if that works. I've not been able to install Net::SSH on my system to tell what's happening. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868001/netsshperl-hands-without-output?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406736/losing-connection-with-netsshperl?rq=1

Comment: You mean another command for the switch in my variable $cmd ? If it's that i tested many commands ofc. But its an interseting things yeah. But i'm pretty sure there is no ssh identificaiton and now i don't know what to think, if it the old version of ssh or my script or what.
I can't test with SSH1 on the Windows prompt but i tested with SSH2 and it works with the Windows prompt but not with an other swtich which accept ssh2.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Your use of wireshark looks clever. I can't think of anything except possibly putting in some print statements in /Net/SSH/Perl/SSH1.pm or running the script with the -d switch if that's allowed.

Comment: In fact i don't realy know where i could put some print statments in SSH1 but it's intersting to work with this file, and i'm not sure to understand what you mean with "-d", i tried to run my script like perl.exe -d ../myscript.pl; it opens a big prompt pannel that i don't know use yet. Thanks for your suggestions :) If i have results i will update my post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it's a problem about my 3 HP switch (2524,5304, 5130). I finally tested on a cisco switch and it works perfeclty........
I will search a solution in they key size or something like that

Edit : i'm using python now and its the same problem but i found the solution here http://forums.juniper.net/t5/ScreenOS-Firewalls-NOT-SRX/Python-Paramiko-with-netscreen/m-p/294864